# Which is the more efficient way of updating data?

Tags: hibernate, orm

There is a table named `company_master` having multiple rows for each user_id. I am updating this table and setting one of its column as `false`.

which way is preferred ?

1) getting the `List<CompanyMaster>` from `company_master` table and then setting status field , and then updating the object in loop

2) writing directly query like this

`Query query= session.createQuery("update CompanyMaster set status=:status where userId= :userId");
        query.setParameterList("status", false);
        query.setParameterList("userId", 1);
        query.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can, in your case you can and you should, use writing a directly query for update or delete operation.  You don't have to select records before and update them, as it's slower than a direct update - you do select with data that you don't need for update / delete, you don't need to iterate it in server side (as it's slower in performance as do it in db side). Also you might have a case when you need to update to big amount of records and in this case select from db in store in java memory, it's just wasted memory comsuption.